# i want to write a function that return first name and first index of second name, i can use the slice but i want the code works automaticly, JS

Tags: javascript, function

```
function returnName(Aname) {
  return // first name and only first charctars of seconed name
}

console.log(returnName(`Ali Ahmad`)); // Ali A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```js
function returnName(name) {
  const [f,s] = name.split(' ')
  return `${f} ${s.charAt(0)}`
}

console.log(returnName(`Ali Ahmad`));
```